# Search for a word in a given string of words

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a string of words that the user can input and I need to search for a specific word in the order given below and take action based on word selected.

- Join, Yes
- Stop,
- Cancel
- Help
- Account
- Card

For example if the User inputs the command `Card Stop` as the input then I should first process the word `Stop` instead of `Card`. Similarly if the user inputs `Join Frank` then I should process the word `Join`. Similarly if user inputs `Stop Help` then I should process `Stop`.

How do I go about doing that?

**EDIT**:

I tried the following but in which case the set of valid words that needs to be searched is put in an Enum and I loop through the split text. But in this case if the user input the word as "Card Stop" then since it one of the correct command in the Enum it simply sends the response of Card and skips the rest. What I would ideally like is it should process Stop instead Card. basically follow the above priority. 
Is that possible?

```
var Tokens = Regex.Split(userText, @"\s+"); 

            foreach (string stringText in Tokens)
            {
                if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TextType), stringText))
                {
                    textType = (TextType)Enum.Parse(typeof(TextType), stringText, true);
                    if ((isTextTypeJoin(textType)))
                    {
                        return textType;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You should provide some code so the community here can give you some feed back.

Comment: *I need to loop through a string of words that the user can input and search for a specific word in the order given below and take action based on word selected.* - sounds like you have answered your own question. That sentence is practically pseudocode. The solution is to learn C#.

Comment: @AntP Edited. Please see my above edited version.

Comment: Sometimes, fancy is hard. It is worth it to not just check each word individually in order (split on spaces and check array contains using IF ELSE)? Do you need to support resource files and the words being changed at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your edit, you need to flip it so you loop through the `enum`, not through the input:

```
foreach(var entry in Enum.GetNames(typeof(TextType)))
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(input, string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", Regex.Escape(entry))))
    {
        return entry;
    }
}

return TextType.SomeDefaultValue;
```

Where `input` is your user-input string. This loops through the enum values and returns the first one that's found in the string.

Comment: In this scenario whatever is found first it will return that. Isn't it? It may not do based on the priority. Will it?

Comment: It *will* be based on "priority," because it loops over your enum values in order. The first one found *is* the highest priority.

Comment: But don't we need to split the input before we do regex match since the input could be multiple words or a sentence..

Comment: No, the regular expression does that for you. `\b` denotes a word boundary. If the word appears at all, it will be found. Try running the code and stepping through it with the debugger - it will help you understand it.

Comment: Ok. Let me try and get back to you if any other questions. Thank you so much.

Comment: Is there anyway to check if only a single word and if it does not match then return right away?

Comment: Yes, but that is a completely new question.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped and I am able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

The temptation here will be to first loop thru the user input, checking your 'priorized' options being sought in the loop. Don't. Loop through your sought options, ckecking the user input for one of them.

- Split the sought words into a `list <string> sought`
- Split the input words into a `list <string> inputs`
- foreach string seek in sought

  - if inputs.contains(seek)

    - take action on seek
    - (it sounds like you want to break out of the loop and stop processing here based on your examples, but your opening sentence implies you should keep looping. )

Comment: Yes, I would like to stop processing if I find the right word.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** - I took out the irrelevant answer
 
Hey sorry for the dumb answer, I started typing before your edit. Anyway, I just thought of a very un-elegant solution, but it works.

```
List<string> input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').ToList();

if(input.Any(x => x == "join")) Console.Write("JOIN");
if(input.Any(x => x == "stop")) Console.Write("STOP");
```

Your would put your if statements in priority order. If you type `stop join` the output would be `JOIN STOP`. Hope this is what you are looking for.

**Edit 2:**

You said that your input isn't from the console, so I thought you could do something like 
`List<string> input = Regex.Split(userText, @"\s+").ToList();` and then use the answer above.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to reply. The problem here is the input command from the User is not via Console. This is one of input as part of a big JSON file that the client calls my RestAPI and so I am not sure if the Console.ReadLine would actually for work for my case.

Comment: I think you could convert `Tokens` using `.ToList()`.

Comment: How will the .ToList() help? Didn't understand. Can you please show through some examples. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. Your answer too helped